# How to (.step) change bjt/fet/opamp models in simulations in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, spice

Is there a way to change bjt/jfet/opamp model in simulation in LTSpice (similarly to changing parameters with .step command)?

I would like to compare different bjt/jfet/opamp models, run a number of simulations with different models, then display the transient/fft curves in the same window, to compare their performance in a given circuit.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Because of the answer you were handed, I learned something new about LTspice!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by using a little trick: the `.param` statement in Spice only works with numbers, but Spice has a way to rename models with numerical names, the `ako` (Also Known As) option. IIRC, this may not be documented in LTSpice docs, but it does exactly what you want. See [ltwiki:AKO Aliases (A Kind Of)](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Undocumented_LTspice#AKO_Aliases_.28A_Kind_Of.29) for a little more information

To sweep models, simply use `.model n ako:<name>` to rename each model you want to sweep, and then use a `.step param MParam list 1 2 .. n` to sweep through those models. See below for an example, where I sweep through three simple diode models plus a "real" diode model.

[image: simulation]
[image: simulation results]

Comment: Very helpful. +1. I knew about and often use "ako". But I hadn't realized that I could use it with LTspice in just that way. It suggests other ideas to me, now, which I may yet apply. Nice to know.

Comment: Stepping through diode models works perfectly, but I couldn't figure out how to step through (opamp) subcircuits? Should this trick work with `.subckt` too?

Comment: @remageFrs did you get it to work with .subckt too ?